# How to reference/including external source files/libraries in C with Visual Studio?

Tags: c, include

Trying to create a C project that references [this](http://mpir.org/) so that I could use it in my own application. Unfortunately I'm having a bit of trouble. I'm a C# programmer and in that language it is very simple. First you reference the library and then you use the `using` keyword.

However, considering I have never programmed in C before I'm having a bit of trouble with this simple task. I tried just copy and pasting all the source files in to my project directory where my main class was also stored but it still couldn't be found. I also tried including the compiled DLL but got the same error:

`error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'mpir.h': No such file or directory`

I'm reading the documentation for it and it says to only do this at the top of your source file:

`#include <mpir.h>`

Which is what I'm doing but it does not seem to be working.. Any suggestions?

Comment: Where did you put the mpir.h file? You need to add that directory to your INCLUDE path. Depending on what version of Visual Studio you're using, you may find the option in the GUI under Tools, Options, Directories, Show directories for = Include files.

Comment: @Raymond: I'm using 2010 and I do not see this option.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7618137/how-to-reference-including-external-source-files-libraries-in-c-with-visual-studi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed this tutorial to get it set up:

http://www.exploringbinary.com/how-to-install-and-run-gmp-on-windows-using-mpir/

Answer (score 0):

If mpir.h is in the same directory as your source file, you need to use the include directive with quotations instead of brackets, like this:

```
#include "mpir.h"
```

Take a look at [Wikipedia's description of including files](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor#Including_files).

Comment: Yeah I tried both and they both give the same error. The only reason I used <> originally was because that was what the documentation suggested for including the file.

Comment: If you are using a header from an external library, angle brackets are more appropriate than double quotes.  (Some would argue that angle brackets are always more appropriate.)

Comment: It sounds like you don't have the library installed correctly.  Normally, you wouldn't copy all the files from a library into your project's source directory, there would be some install mechanism that would copy the library's header and library files into appropriate system directories.
The documentation probably assumes that the library's files are correctly installed and part of the C compiler's include path.